# Bing Maps: Two Maps on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm trying to display two Bing maps on the same webpage, however my code is only displaying the second map (see code below).

I've already tried with async (scripts at end of `<body>`) and sync (scripts inside `<head>`) options but I'm getting the same error.

Any idea of how to fix it? Appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
    <h1>Map 1: </h1>
    <div id='myMap' style='width: 30vw; height: 30vh;'></div>

    <h1>Map 2:</h1>
    <div id='myMap2' style='width: 30vw; height: 30vh;'></div>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var loc1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.777677, 9.180600); //Schloßplatz coords

            var navigationBarMode1 = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;
            var map1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key',
                navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode1.compact, //uncomment to show/hide compact navigation bar
                center: loc1,
                zoom: 16,
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var loc2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.777677, 9.180600); //Schloßplatz coords

            var navigationBarMode2 = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;
            var map2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap2'), {
                credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key',
                navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode2.compact, //uncomment to show/hide compact navigation bar
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
                center: loc2,
                zoom: 16,
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one function with the same name the last to be defined will override the others.

You can merge your code in to one function which will allow you to create both maps in the script callback:

```
<script>
    function loadMapScenario() {
        var loc1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.777677, 9.180600); //Schloßplatz coords

        var navigationBarMode1 = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;
        var map1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
            credentials: 'BING MAPS KEY',
            navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode1.compact, //uncomment to show/hide compact navigation bar
            center: loc1,
            zoom: 16,
        });

        var loc2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.777677, 9.180600); //Schloßplatz coords

        var navigationBarMode2 = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;
        var map2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap2'), {
            credentials: 'BING MAPS KEY',
            navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode2.compact, //uncomment to show/hide compact navigation bar
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
            center: loc2,
            zoom: 16,
        });
    }
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
```

Since both maps are using identical coordinates and `NavigationBarMode`s you don't need to duplicate these variables which would save a couple of lines:

```
<script>
    function loadMapScenario() {
        var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.777677, 9.180600); //Schloßplatz coords

        var navigationBarMode = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;

        var map1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
            credentials: 'BING MAPS KEY',
            navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode.compact, 
            center: loc1,
            zoom: 16,
        });

        var map2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap2'), {
            credentials: 'BING MAPS KEY',
            navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode.compact, // use 'navigationBarMode' instead of 'navigationBarMode2'
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
            center: loc, // use 'loc' instead of 'loc2'
            zoom: 16,
        });
    }
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have 2 methods with the same name.

```
function loadMapScenario
```

The first function definition will be overwritten with the second function definition.

Change the name of the second function, which should take care of the issue or include both the snippets inside a single function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it.